# Magento 2.3.2: $this->getChildBlock()->setData()->toHtml(); not working in loop

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2

```
return $this->getChildBlock("child block name")->setField("data")->toHtml();
```

This add code in Block file and rendor this function in phtml but code doesn't work, Is there any solution ?

Comment: Try `setData("name", "value")`

Comment: No Child block render issue,